# Crackling sound with Realtek audio driver - Dell Computer

Tags: windows-10, laptop, audio, drivers, microphone

I have a dell Inspiron 14 - 7472 with freshly installed windows 10. I updated all my drivers using Dell Support Assist software and made sure I was updated with windows 10. I had this issue before reinstalling windows 10 and I thought that reinstalling it would solve. I was wrong.

Whenever I watch HD videos, play games or anything related, my audio will make crackling sounds. And whenever these sounds appear, my notebook stutters and gets slower. This happens when I'm on speakers or headphones/sets. This does NOT happen when I uninstall the Realtek audio and use the Windows 10 - High Definition Audio. Thus, it is an audio issue.

Realtek version - 6.0.9000.1 (08/04/2020).

Why wouldn't I use the High Definition Audio then? Because I have a p3 jack input. By using this driver, I couldn't make my headset's microphone be recognized by windows. If you have any solutions I deeply appreciate it.

Many thanks in advance :)

Comment: It is "normal" for sound to crackle or stutter when the computer slows or is under load, so it may be that the sound is a *symptom* rather than the issue. One thing that you might try is to set the audio for the mic and headphones to a higher bit depth and sampling rate. This may seem counterintuitive, but I know from experience from using realtek chipsets with DAW (multitrack recording) that this can reduce latency. The theory being that the higher bit depth and sampling is "native" for the chipset and the lower sampling and bit depth requires CPU to "transcode." Probably only impacts the mic

Comment: Could be due to Windows update: see https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-other_settings-winpc/speakers-crackling-since-windows-10-update/a32ea055-4512-4cf9-9a73-46906b28efdb